# Compound index with nested object... Do or dont?

Tags: mongodb

I'm pretty sure I have read somewhere that there might be problems/bugs regarding creating indexes with nested objects. Like this:

```
db.bookings.ensureIndex({"staff._id": 1, "start": 1, "end": 1})
```

Can someone please confirm or deny this?

I can't seemt to find anything online confirming possible problems/bugs. And the index seems to be in use when I run a test query with `explain()`?

Comment: Is `staff` an array or just a nested object?

Comment: It's just a nested object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not finding anything because indexes that reference fields of nested objects operate the same as ones that only reference top-level fields.

You may be recalling some of the potential issues you can face when including a field of an object that's nested within an array.  That's when things can get messy.  See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/#limitations